# ¿Hacer Foreign Key sin ser Primary Key en Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo estas tablas en mysql. Necesito añadir de la tabla OPERATORE y ATTIVITA los campos id_vitaever. Estos no pueden ser primary key pero necesito guardarlos en la tabla EVENTO.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `operatore`;
CREATE TABLE `operatore` (
    `cognome` varchar(255),
    `nome` varchar(255),
    `codice_Fiscale` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
    `id_vitaever` int,
    PRIMARY KEY (`codice_Fiscale`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attivita`;
CREATE TABLE `attivita` (
    `id_attivita` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_vitaever` VARCHAR(12),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_attivita`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `evento`;
CREATE TABLE `evento` (
    `id_event` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_attivita` INT,
    `id_vitaever_Attiv` VARCHAR(12),
    `id_vitaever_Oper` int,
    `codice_Fiscale_user` VARCHAR(17),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_event`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`codice_Fiscale_user`) REFERENCES `operatore` (`codice_Fiscale`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_attivita`) REFERENCES `attivita` (`id_attivita`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

## Indice

He intentado agregar un **indice** pero me da error.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Ix_id_vitaever_Attiv ON Cliente(id_vitaever)
GO
ALTER TABLE evento ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_vitaever_Attiv)
REFERENCES attivita (id_vitaever);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Ix_id_vitaever_Oper ON operatore(id_vitaever)
GO
ALTER TABLE evento ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_vitaever_Oper)
REFERENCES operatore (id_vitaever);
```

## Error:

Error que me genera mysql

```
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'GO
ALTER TABLE evento ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_vitaever_Attiv)
REFERENCES attivita (i' en la linea 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quitando el GO va perfectamente.

```
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Ix_id_vitaever_Attiv ON attivita(id_vitaever);
    ALTER TABLE evento ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_vitaever_Attiv)
    REFERENCES attivita (id_vitaever);

    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Ix_id_vitaever_Oper ON operatore(id_vitaever);
    ALTER TABLE evento ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_vitaever_Oper)
    REFERENCES operatore (id_vitaever);
```

Comment: esto es una respuesta a tu pregunta?

Comment: Sí, quitando el GO, me he dado cuenta de que va

Comment: Entonces por favor considera agregar una explicación para que se comprenda mejor